# Adding a DSL modem as a client device in a wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

Currently, I have a DSL modem with built in wireless router, provider by the ISP. As the hardware is quite poor, the speed and range of this wireless network is rather limited. There are some wire ethernet connections on the device, but unfortunately, adding cables in my house is not possible.

In order to improve the performance of the network, I thought of the following setup.

- A new gigabit, wireless router in my home office. As my desktop computer, network printer, nas... are located in this room, they can all be wired to the router, ensuring optimal speed. This router would also serve as DHCP server.
- Mobile devices (smartphone, laptop, ...) can connect to the wireless network provided by this router.
- The ISP provided modem/router added as a slave device (DHCP server disabled, fixed IP assigned) to the existing wireless network using a repeater/range extender (e.g. TL-WA830RE from TP-Link, http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1247&model=TL-WA830RE)

As I'm not completely in to network architectures, I have some questions:
- Is it possible to add a DSL modem as a 'client'/slave device in an existing network.
- Is a repeater (e.g. TL-WA830RE) the correct hardware needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the new gigabit router, call your ISP and ask if the DSL modem can be put in bridge mode.  This would make it transparent to the network - you'd enter all of your account info in on your own router, and it would be the only router on the network.  Much simpler than trying to manage both devices on the same network.

Comment: This is correct. The ideal setup is for your Router to have the public IP address, and the modem functions in bridge mode. You want to avoid dual NAT.

If your ISP uses PPPoE, simply removing your credentials from the Modem and inserting them into the router could do the trick. If your ISP uses DHCP, you can probably still use bridge mode, but might require more config.

Comment: The DSL modem is a Sagem F@st 3464, using PPPoE. According to this website (http://en.wiki.edpnet.be/index.php/Sagem_Fast_3464_-_bridge_mode), it is possible to put it into bridge mode. One question remains to me however: when in bridge mode, will it be able to connect to the wireless network, or will that only work if I connect it to the router using a LAN port? (I don't have the new router yet...)

Comment: In bridge mode, your router becomes the wireless access point (it would need to be wired to the DSL modem).  Reading your comments below, it looks like you really want a wireless bridge, which would allow you to hardwire the NAS and PC  in one room, but have them communicate with the internet over the wireless.  It's a complicated solution, but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the DSL device. I can with mine (D-Link). But unless you want to put the wifi far from the DSL modem, I would leave the DHCP on on the DSL device and connect the gigabit wifi with a short cable to the DSL device. Then the wireless router will usually bridge wired and wifi networks, and you'll be ready to go. No need for repeater then.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to put the gigabit router in another room, allowing wired interconnections between the desktop computer and nas to the router resulting in a higher network speed. Putting the router next to the modem, would result in all data transfer from desktop to the NAS over the (slow) wireless network...